# reactive selectInput choices and selected values cannot be reset to NULL correctly

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny app, I'd pop the columns selected in `input$columns` to `input$vars`, and then the selection in `input$vars` is popped to `input$fromvars` for further selection. However my code doesn't work properly when I deselected all columns in `inut$columns` (I tested with `renderPrint` and it shows `input$columns` is "NULL") , as I expect not only `input$vars` value is NULL(it works), but also the choices in this selectInput shall be NULL with nothing left in the dropdown list for selection, however, I click on the dropdown list and find that the last selection in the last `input$columns` is displayed.

Worse for `input$fromvars`, I expect its value is reset to NULL as input$vars is reset to NULL(upon change of selection in `input$columns`), also the choices should be reset to NULL so that nothing shown in the drop down list. However, this doesn't work unless I manually udpate `input$vars`.

Below please find my code, would anyone please help look into this?

```
if(interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 

      fileInput("file", "Choose CSV File",
                # limit the file extention to the following:
                accept=c("text/csv", 
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", 
                         ".csv")),

      h5("Upload file for data analysis"),


      # no choices before a file uploaded
      uiOutput("columns"),

      # inputs to generate pivot table (demo in a single tab here, but in real app, this will be on a different tab)
      selectInput("vars", "vars to use:", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL),
      selectInput("fromvars", "select from vars:", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL)

      ),

    mainPanel( 
      verbatimTextOutput("print")
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dt <- reactiveValues()

  # upload file
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    inFile <- input$file
    req(inFile)
    # upload the file to dataset
    dt$data = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
  })


  # create columns groupcheckbox ui
  output$columns <- renderUI({

    # get the col names of f and assign them to a list
    cols = mapply(list, names(dt$data))

    # render column group checkbox ui after loading the data
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Select columns to display", choices = cols, selected = cols)
  })

  #########################################
  # blocks with problem
  #########################################

  ######## dependent on columns selection ########
  observeEvent(input$columns, {
    dt$cols <- input$columns
    # update input$vars for pivottable tab
    updateSelectInput(session, "vars", "vars to use:", choices = dt$cols, selected = NULL)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)


  observeEvent(input$vars, {
    if( is.null(input$vars)) { 
      updateSelectInput(session, "fromvars", "select from vars:", choices = NULL, selected = NULL)  
    }
    else {
      updateSelectInput(session, "fromvars", "select from vars:", choices = isolate(input$vars), selected = NULL)
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$print <- renderPrint(
    list(
      paste("input$vars:",input$vars), 
      paste("input$columns:", input$columns),
      paste("input$fromvars:", input$fromvars)
    )
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are very close. The only real problem is that `updateSelectInput` seems to **not** like `NULL` values in its `choices` parameters so you have to avoid those.

I got the code to work by making the following changes:

- in `observerEvent(input$columns,` added a statement that sets `dt$cols`to an empty string `""` if it has the value `NULL`
- in `observerEvent(input$vars,` the `choices=NULL` was changed to `choices=""`
- adjusted the `renderPrint` statements to make a nicer printout (using double `pastes` so label doesn't get repeated.

Here is the code to verify:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 

      fileInput("file", "Choose CSV File",
                # limit the file extention to the following:
                accept=c("text/csv", 
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", 
                         ".csv")),

      h5("Upload file for data analysis"),

      # no choices before a file uploaded
      uiOutput("columns"),

      # inputs to generate pivot table (demo in a single tab here, but in real app, this will be on a different tab)
      selectInput("vars", "vars to use:", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL),
      selectInput("fromvars", "select from vars:", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel( 
      verbatimTextOutput("print")
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dt <- reactiveValues()

  # upload file
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    inFile <- input$file
    req(inFile)
    # upload the file to dataset
    dt$data = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
  })

  # create columns groupcheckbox ui
  output$columns <- renderUI({

    # get the col names of f and assign them to a list
    cols = mapply(list, names(dt$data))

    # render column group checkbox ui after loading the data
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Select columns to display", choices = cols, selected = cols)
  })

  #########################################
  # blocks with problem
  #########################################

  ######## dependent on columns selection ########
  observeEvent(input$columns, {
    dt$cols <- input$columns
    if (is.null(dt$cols)) dt$cols <- ""
    # update input$vars for pivottable tab
    print("observerEvent")
    print(dt$cols)

    updateSelectInput(session, "vars", "vars to use:", choices = dt$cols, selected = NULL)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)


  observeEvent(input$vars, {
    if( is.null(input$vars)) { 
      updateSelectInput(session, "fromvars", "select from vars:", choices = "", selected = NULL)  
    }
    else {
      updateSelectInput(session, "fromvars", "select from vars:", choices = input$vars, selected = NULL)
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$print <- renderPrint(
    list(
      paste("input$columns:", paste(input$columns,collapse=",")),
      paste("input$vars:",paste(input$vars,collapse=",")), 
      paste("input$fromvars:", paste(input$fromvars,collapse=","))
    )
  )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is solved! I wonder why this is not documented in Shiny package.

Comment: Sorry just did. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that. Check your older answers too. At least one of those it looks to me like you should accept.